# Replicating SDR transmitter and receiver (shifting of a quadrature signal)

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency, software-defined-radio, numpy

I am trying to implement an SDR transmitter and receiver based on the description [here](https://pysdr.org/content/sampling.html).

```
def sdr_transmitter(signal: np.ndarray, frequency: float, sample_period: float):
    """
    Encode input signal in the form of IQ values to output signal.
    """

    Is = signal[:, 0]
    Qs = signal[:, 1]

    t = np.arange(0, signal.shape[0] * sample_period, sample_period)

    in_phase = Is * np.cos(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)
    quadrature = Qs * np.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)

    signal = in_phase + quadrature

    return signal

def sdr_receiver(signal: np.ndarray, frequency: float, sample_period: float):
    """
    Takes the signal and extracts the in-phase and quadrature components.
    In other words, extracts the cosine and sine components, the I and Q.
    """
    t = np.arange(0, signal.shape[0] * sample_period, sample_period)

    cos_wave = np.cos(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)
    sin_wave = np.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)

    Is = signal * cos_wave
    Qs = signal * sin_wave

    output = np.stack([Is, Qs], axis=-1)

    return output
```

and I test it like this:

```
sample_period = 0.02
Is = np.full(100, fill_value=1)
Qs = np.full(100, fill_value=1)
signal = np.stack([Is, Qs], axis=-1)

output = sdr_transmitter(signal, frequency=2, sample_period=sample_period)
signal_output = sdr_receiver(output, frequency=2, sample_period=sample_period)
```

where the `signal` and `signal_output` should equal. However, they do not. Since the `Is` and `Qs` are constant, I should get the same constant values after demodulation by the receiver. I believe that by multiplying by sin and cos waves, I should get those values thanks to the Frequency Shift Property (from [here](https://pysdr.org/content/frequency_domain.html)):
$$e^{2 \pi j f_0 t}x(t) \leftrightarrow X(f-f_0)$$

Thus, after subtraction of the frequency, the resulting frequency should be zero, which means that only constant values remain, and in fact, the constant values should be equal to the original `Is` and `Qs`. What I observed is the opposite; the frequency increased (see the plots below).

**Transmitter**: Let's look at the signals inside of the transmitter using the example above. Note that the in-phase signal overlaps with the cosine since the `Is` are all equal to 1.

[image: The signals inside of a transmitter]

**Receiver**: Now, let's see what happens when the signal is multiplied by cosine and check whether the `Is` are what we expect.

[image]

We can see that the `Is` do not represent a constant function at 1, but instead, it is a wave with a higher frequency than the signal or the cosine.

Apparently, I misunderstood something and can't figure out what. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal given as by `signal = in_phase + quadrature` is a real passband signal with `Is` and `Qs` as a complex baseband signal. (This should actually be `signal = in_phase - quadrature` to avoid spectrum reversal, only noted as this isn't the OP's primary issue but noted.)  For down-conversion, additional low pass filtering is required to remove the high frequency (double frequency) component.  In the OP's case, simple averaging (which is a low pass filter) will result in the expected constant function.

Both processes are given from the shift property of the Fourier Transform which states that multiplying a function $x(t)$ in the time domain by $e^{j\omega_c t}$ will shift the frequency by $\omega_c$. If $\omega_c$ is positive the frequency will be translated up, and if $\omega_c$ is negative the frequency will will be translated down:

$$\mathscr{F}\{x(t)e^{j\omega_c t}\} \leftrightarrow X(\omega-\omega_c)$$

The function $e^{j\omega_c t}$ itself is a "spinning phasor" in the time domain, and has a transform as a single impulse in the frequency domain (a single frequency tone, and thus a sinusoid consists of two tones as positive and negative frequency components). Multiplication in time is convolution in frequency, which results in a simple shift. Also multiplying exponentials results in a summation of the exponents which may also provide further mathematical intuition:  $e^{j\omega_1 t}e^{j\omega_o t} = e^{j(\omega_1+\omega_o)t}$.

I will use $x(t)$ as the original baseband waveform and $Real\{y(t)\}$ as the real passband waveform:

$$x(t) = I_s+jQ_s$$

$$e^{j\omega_c t} = \cos(\omega_c t) + j\sin(\omega_c t) = I_c+jQ_c$$

$$y(t) = x(t)e^{j\omega_c t} = (I_s+jQ_s)(I_c+jQ_c)$$

$$Real\{y(t)\} = Real\{(I_sI_c-Q_sQ_c) + j(I_cQ_s + I_sQ_c)  \}=I_sI_c-Q_sQ_c$$

Thus:

$$Real\{y(t)\} = I_s\cos(\omega_c t) - Q_s\sin(\omega_c t)$$

The following graphics below showing upconversion should also help provide further insight and intuition in the frequency translation process:

[image: Upconversion]

Down-conversion proceeds in reverse by multiplying $y(t)$ by $e^{-j\omega_c t}$ where a high frequency component must be removed by low pass filtering (or use the Hilbert Transform to recreate a one-sided complex passband signal):

[image: down-conversion]

Using $y_r(t)$ as the real passband signal, and $x_b(t)$ as the recovered baseband signal, the process is given as:

$$x_b(t) = \text{LPF}\{y_r(t)e^{-j\omega_c t}\}$$

$$x_b(t) = \text{LPF}\{y_r(t)(I_c-jQ_c)\}$$

Thus prior to low pass filtering the recovered complex baseband signal is given as:

$$I_b(t) = y_r(t)\cos(\omega_c(t))$$

$$Q_b(t)= -y_r(t)\sin(\omega_c(t))$$

Alternatively to avoid the need for filtering, the Hilbert Transform can be used to create the Analytic Signal, which converts the real passband into a complex passband with positive frequency components only (which would have the frequency spectrum as depicted in the third row of the first plot). The analytic signal is returned by the `hilbert` function in MATLAB, Octave and Python’s scipy.signal library. This can then be down-converted by multiplying by $e^{-j\omega t}$.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! It sheds light on several perks of signal processing. I did not realize that after the down-conversion I would be left with a high-frequency signal that I need to filter.  

I would only add that to get the original signal `Is` being transmitted, one must multiply the filtered down-converted signal by 2. This is because the original signal is decomposed into two parts (with positive and negative frequency), one of which is filtered away. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You're not wrong but there is no necessity to multiply by 2 specifically. There will be gain in the receiver (likely not "2") to normalize the waveform based on whatever loss the signal has. But your thinking is correct. Half of that signal is filtered away with that approach (and half of the noise as well, so there is no actual loss when we consider SNR)